# WPF TreeView - Slow Performance in Keyboard Navigation

Tags: wpf, data-binding, treeview

I have a TreeView which is populated runtime. It is defined like this:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RootItem.ChildItems}">

  <TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TreeViewItem}">
      <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="{Binding IsExpanded, Mode=TwoWay}" />
      <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" />
    </Style>
  </TreeView.ItemContainerStyle>

  <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
  ...    
  </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
</TreeView>
```

I am using the part with the Style / Setter to making it possible for me to bind the two properties `IsSelected` and `IsExpanded` to properties of the same name (of type `bool`) of the base items as I am using them to determine when and how to asynchronously load in the child items.

The items displayed on the treeview all inherit from the same base class. The property I bind to looks like this:

```
public bool IsExpanded
{
  get { return _IsExpanded; }
  set
  {
    if (HasAsynchChildItems)
      if (value)
        LoadChildItems();
      else if (!value)
        Collapse();
    _IsExpanded = value;
  }
}
```

`HasAsynchChildItems` is a propertay that determines if child items should be loaded in asynchronously or not. `LoadChildItems()` is the one loading them. It's async.

As long as there are only a few items, everything works fine.

<strike>At a certain point down the tree there are about 2500+ items and the app begins to become unresponsive and take about 20-30 sec to load. Not only that, but after they are loaded, the app hangs againg for 10+ seconds when I change selection.</strike>

All of those items that cause the app to become slow have `HasAsycnchChildItems` set to false. So `LoadChildItems()` does not start.

Is the problem that I am binding via style setter?

PS: I have also monitored the thing with Performance Explorer, and Visual Studio tells me that 90% of processing time goes down in `PresentationFramework.ni.dll`.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

After a bit more investigation, I need to update the question:

1. I found that loading really is fast. The items almost instantly display after they're retrieved from the DB.
2. Selecting and expanding is also almost instant.
3. What really stalls hangs the application, **is navigating through the nodes via keyboard (up + down arrow)**. It takes about 15sec each. If I change selection via mouse click, it is immediate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found some kind of workaround.

As I stated above in my comment (and therefore I edited my original question again) I have found out that the problem lies neither in DataBinding, nor is it any other data-related issued. It is just an issue with the TreeView control itself, and how it handles keyboard navigation.

The issue appears **only** if you navigate through the TreeView by **UpArrow** or **DownArrow**.

It does not happen with **PageDown**, **PageUp** or **Mouse-Click**.

So here is what I did. First of all, I enabled virtualization on my TreeView, which alone already improved things a lot, but was not yet satisfying:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=RootItem.Items}" Grid.Row="1"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
          VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling"
```

The second thing I did was writing my own custom event handler to handle navigation through the TreeView by ArrowUp / ArrowDown. I must add that I totally dislike writing code like that (and it is also just a result of a quick test / experiment, so maybe dere be dragons!). Further: all items in my TreeView inherit from the base class `ManagementItem` that provides `IsSelected`, `IsExpanded`, `Index` (which indicates the position of the item inside the parent's child items).

```
private void TreeView_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
  var tv = sender as TreeView;
  var item = tv.SelectedItem as ManagementItem;

  e.Handled = false;

  if (e.Key == Key.Down)
    try
    {
      if (item.IsExpanded)
        item.Items.First().IsSelected = true;
      else
        if (item.Index == item.Owner.Items.Count - 1)
          item.Owner.Owner.Items[item.Owner.Index + 1].IsSelected = true;
        else
          item.Owner.Items[item.Index + 1].IsSelected = true;
      e.Handled = true;
    } catch {}

  if (e.Key == Key.Up)
    try
    {
      if (item.Index == 0)
        item.Owner.IsSelected = true;
      else
        item.Owner.Items[item.Index - 1].IsSelected = true;
      e.Handled = true;
    } catch {}

 }
```

This increased navigation performance drastically.

Comment: Truly an awesome discovery and solution.  How this solution does not have far more upvotes is puzzling.  Perhaps it is because few use WPF TreeView for large numbers of items given its extremely poor support for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that is getting called for all the items
Try

```
public bool IsExpanded
{
  get { return _IsExpanded; }
  set
  {
      if (_IsExpanded == value) return;
      _IsExpanded = value;
      if (HasAsynchChildItems)
      {
          if (_IsExpanded)
            LoadChildItems();
          else 
            Collapse();
      }        
   }
}
```

And once you LoadChildItems() save the results so you don't have to load them again

Comment: I have updated my question. The items actually load and display instantly. But as soon as I navigate through them by keyboard (up / down arrow) it takes extremely long. It does not happen when changing selection via mouse-click.

Comment: Well that certainly changes the question

Answer (score 0):

I confirmed Hemisphera´s workaround. It actually gets the treeview navigation working as expected.

I have a TreeView with 2 initial levels: First 5K nodes, second level 20K nodes (~4 children per parent node). Default WPF navigation took 3-4 sec moving from one node to the other. This implementation does that in ~100ms

Couple of things to consider when Implementing this:

1. Create a base class for your TreeViewItems model (In Hemisphera's code, the *ManagementItem* class). Include the required properties (IsSelected, IsExpanded, Index and *Parent* or *Owner* as Hemisphera´s code shows).
2. Don´t forget to implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your base class. Also, you need to trigger the events when IsExpanded and IsSelected are set. This is needed for the TwoWayBinding:

   ```
   private bool _isExpanded;
   public bool IsExpanded
   {
       get { return _isExpanded; }
       set
       {
           _isExpanded = value;
           if (PropertyChanged != null)
               PropertyChanged(this, IsExpandedEventsArgs);
       }
   }

   private bool _isSelected;
   public bool IsSelected 
   { 
       get {return _isSelected;}
       set
       {
           _isSelected = value;
           if (PropertyChanged != null)
               PropertyChanged(this, IsSelectedEventArgs);
       }
   }
   ```
3. There are some corner cases to consider in the TreeView_PreviewKeyDown method . I.e: Nodes at the higher level don't have an Parent (or Owner). The key up logic, also needs to handle the *IsExpanded* attribute when changing from one higher level node to a lower level node which is expanded.