# TreeView items keyboard navigation, focus, etc

Tags: c#, wpf, navigation, treeview, focus

Sometimes I am really disappointed with how WPF designers discard obvious things. They require from us to solve problems where shouldn't be any ...

`TreeView`, as simple as this (in reality it has data-templates, but problems reproduce-able with just this):

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeViewItem Header="123" IsExpanded="True">
        <TreeViewItem Header="1" />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox Width="100" />
            <Button Content="Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <TreeViewItem Header="3" />
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

Now if you try to navigate that **with keyboard only**:

- it is impossible to set focus to button;
- when passing from up or down through `ListViewItem` with `TextBox` it get focus on <kbd>Up</kbd> or <kbd>Down</kbd> key and then it stay there **forever** (I don't see a way to bypass that, <kbd>Tab</kbd> key behave really weird with `TreeView`).

Am I doing something wrong or there are some secret helper classes I have to use to make that default expected by user behavior to happens?

P.S.: I can solve that specific problem with some attached properties (aka *behaviors*) to preview key presses on `TextBox`.. I think. I am just finished doing something similar with `ListView` and I am tired. Maybe I miss something obvious which everybody else knows? Then tell me please.

Answer (score 1):

I can hint to you this solution (no additional code, just standard attached properties). You can use the [KeyboardNavigation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Input.KeyboardNavigation(v=vs.110).aspx) class and three of its attached properties.

Take a look to this XAML:

```
<TreeView>
    <TreeViewItem Header="123" IsExpanded="True">
        <TreeViewItem Header="1" />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" KeyboardNavigation.TabNavigation="Cycle"
                                                KeyboardNavigation.ControlTabNavigation="Continue"
                                                KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="None">
            <TextBox Width="100" Margin="5" TabIndex="1" />
            <Button Content="Click" Margin="5" TabIndex="2" />
        </StackPanel>
        <TreeViewItem Header="3" />
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

Now, I added margin in order to make more visible which control is focused. Moreover I added TaxIndex property for making <kbd>Tab</kbd> key work properly.

Let's see now how the navigation for outer TreeView works. You can move among nodes by using directional keys (in the usual way).

When you select the second child (the one that contains the `StackPanel`) you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> in order to "enter" the node. The first time you press those two key, you focus the TextBox. The second time you focus the Button. The third time you "exit" the node.

Moreover if either the `TextBox` or the `Button` is focused, you can push <kbd>Tab</kbd> in order to cycle between those two controls. Whenever you need <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> allows you to break cycling.

So each key has its own task and you can move along the TreeView as you wish. Can it be suitable for your needs? I hope so.

Comment: It was very helpful, thanks. `DirectionalNavigation=None` seems disable arrow keys giving focus to elements inside container. This was the most annoying thing. Is there a way to use `Tab` key to enter container and cycle between elements inside? I am not really a big fun of `Ctr`+`Tab` (nor users of my software will be). As a user I would expect `Enter` or `Tab` key will give focus to `TextBox`. Or, even better, anything what is not navigation keys (not arrow keys, pgup/pgdown, tab, shift+tab, etc.).  I tried all combinations of `TabNavigation` property, but none makes `Tab` to focus textbox.

Comment: @Sinatr AFAIK those keys are the standard one for the standard keyboard navigation mode. I guess that if you want to use `Enter` instead of `Ctrl` + `Tab`, probably you have to write some code. Indeed if you look at `Navigate` method in the `KeyboardNavigation` class, you will see that those keys are hardcoded and it does not seem it is possible to customize them in an easy way.

Comment: Yep, as a user I'd expect `Enter` or `Tab` to get focus inside currently selected node in `TreeView`. That `Ctr`+`Tab` is terribly bad idea, but I understand the point of using it, wpf guys wanted something to navigate **into** container (which `Tab` should do in my opinion), but to be different from `Tab`. I played with your solution and run into a [performance problem](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31007104/1997232). No idea why but datatemplated treeview become terribly slow when I try to use `KeyboardNavigation`.